# howto reduce the size of UIImage on Iphone?

Tags: uiimage

if  screen image is captured which is 320x480, how can I reduce that UIIMage to something like 80x120

Answer (score 0):

You can do this two different ways:

1 - If you just want to draw the image with a different size, just scale its parent (e.g. UIImageView.)

2 - Scale the UIImage itself; this involves drawing the image to a context and then grabbing the contents. Here's a site that shows how to do this: http://iosdevelopertips.com/graphics/how-to-scale-an-image-using-an-objective-c-category.html